# Sequence of functions and integral multiple choice question

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Define $f_n(x)= 1 $, if $x\in [-n-2,-n)$ and $f_n(x)=0$ otherwise.
Let $\alpha=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) \, dx$ and $\beta=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_n(x) \, dx$. then

1. $0<\alpha <1, ~\beta=1$
2. $\alpha=0,~\beta=\infty$
3. $\alpha=\beta=0$
4. $\alpha=0,~\beta=2$

We may be required to check the uniform convergence of this sequence. I am not able to do much

Comment: $\lim f_n(x)=0$ for all $x$ and $\int f_n(x)=2$ for all $n$.

Comment: This sequence does not converge uniformly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x$. Then for large enough $n$, $x \notin [-n-2,n) $ so $f_n(x) = 0$. Consequently, for all $x$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0$. Thus, $\alpha = \int_{-\infty}^\infty 0dx = 0$.

---

Fix $n$, then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_n(x) \,dx = \int_{-n-2}^{-n} 1\,dx = -n - (-n-2) = 2$. Thus, $\beta = \lim_{n \to \infty} 2 = 2$.

---

The above serves as a counterexample to the exchange of limit and integral. The reason you cannot apply DCT is because any function pointwise dominating all the $f_n$ is positive and bounded away from $0$ hence not integrable on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: even for large $n$, $f_n(x)=1$ on an interval, how overcame this?

Comment: The point is, when we are calculating $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$, we are doing so for **fixed** $x$. For example, what is $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(-666667)$? For every $n > 666669$, the number $f_n(-666667)$ evaluates to zero because $-666667$ does not belong to $[-n-2,-n)$. So, the sequence $f_n(-666667)$, as $n$ moves to $\infty$, becomes $0$. This happens for every $x$, not just $-666667$ for example.  So, $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0$ *for all* $x$.

Comment: However, as $n$ moves, the integral of $f_n$ does not change,because the way the $f_n$ are defined, as $n$ increases the graph of $f_n$ just pushes to the left without changing shape, form or magnitude, so the integral is unchanged because the graph is unchanged up to translation.